# Showing div container via data-date from another html page

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

i want to show the newest div containers from another html page inside my website on a second page.

so i have the page news.html and on this page i write some news in div containers like this:

```
<div class="guidediv" data-date="September 14 2023">    
NEWS TEXT NEWS TEXT
</div>

<div class="guidediv" data-date="September 07 2023">    
NEWS TEXT NEWS TEXT
</div>

<div class="guidediv" data-date="September 01 2023">    
NEWS TEXT NEWS TEXT
</div>

<div class="guidediv" data-date="August 24 2023">   
NEWS TEXT NEWS TEXT
</div>

<div class="guidediv" data-date="August 18 2023">   
NEWS TEXT NEWS TEXT
</div>

and so on
```

Now i want to the news of the last 10 days on a second page like start.html

Is this possible?

Comment: How about making a common 'content' page with the data you need on both pages, and then just use it inside of each page?

Comment: what would be the advantage? and how would this worK?

Comment: Advantage would be that you have reusable content so you don;t have to write the same or very similar code on each instance of usage over and over again. Check if this can help you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reusable-html-components-how-to-reuse-a-header-and-footer-on-a-website/
Or you can search web for 'html reusable content' or 'html templates'. Good luck.